# Div not appearing until resize/highlight

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

This is literally the weirdest thing that's ever happened to me in my career of web design... For some reason, in Chrome, the bottom ⅔ of my webpage doesn't display unless I:

1. Highlight any of the webpage
2. Resize the window
3. Scroll up and down a few times

I'm using 2 divs to house all of the content in the webpage, one `div` fades after 2 seconds, and one fades 2 seconds after that (this is the effect you see when loading the page).

For some reason, when I remove the second `div`, the problem doesn't happen. Here's the site, and if there's any other information I can provide you with, let me know! Any help is much appreciated.

http://committee-of-taste.co.uk/test/index.html

Answer (score 0):

Is there meant to be something below the photos? If not, it's working fine in Chrome for me. Perhaps you could share a screenshot of what your seeing?

Comment: Thanks a lot for your reply, If you can see the photo's, then it's working fine, but for some reason when i load the page i can't see them unless i resize the page!